Most efficient way to load an array of observables (slow network requests) based on an initial observable (fast network request)?
So the situation is I load a list of objects (in this case users) to display. Most of the user data pulls very fast but the photo fetch is rather slow. Rather than pulling all of the data including photos in one request, I want to pull all the data except for photos in one request, and then pull all the photos as separate requests. I don't care if the photos are initially populated or not, I want the data and structure to populate on the page first, and the photos to appear as they load.
I'm having some issues getting this to work; my app hangs. I'm thinking it could be because of how apollo client doesn't play nice with async pipes in angular... but I'm not sure. I'm not fetching that many photo requests yet, but they don't seem to go through and my network tab has not finishing requests.
page.html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img [src]="getUserPhotoUrl(user.username)" />
    </div>
    <span>{{user.username}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>

page.ts
class {
  users$: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.apollo.watchQuery<users: User[]>({query: usersQuery}).valueChanges.pipe(map(result => result.data.users));
  }

  getUserPhotoUrl(username: string) {
    return this.http.get(`.../user/${username}/photo`);
  }

}


The browser has a limit of parallel API calls 6 (google search) so, an efficient way to fetch the data is using batches of 6.

Ideally you would serve the images on the API itself, if that is not an option, then you can try a lazy observable stream.
We use image property which we add on the user object to hold a placeholder image, this will be shown after the actual image loads, we can show a spinner gif also.
ngOnInit() {
  this.user$ = this.apollo.watchQuery<users: User[]>({query: usersQuery}).valueChanges.pipe(map(result => result.data.users.map((data: any) => {
    data.image = 'https://placehold.co/600x400'// placeholder image
    return data;
  })));
  this.lazyLoadImages();
}

After this we create a new observable stream, this stream is responsible for loading the images. This stream features first getting the data from the stream using switchMap, so that new value changes, stop the previous incomplete image loads. Then we use from to convert the array to an observable stream that emits each value. We are using bufferCount to convert the emissions to batches of 6 values. These batches are fed to a concatMap, so that it executes in order. Then finally for each user, we convert it to an observable using the map array operator, this is used in forkJoin to execute the APIs. Then use tap to update the user object with the image.
lazyLoadImages() {
  if(this.sub) {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
  this.sub = this.user$.pipe(
    switchMap((usersData: any) => from(usersData).pipe(
      bufferCount(6),
      concatMap((users: any) => {
        const imagesApis = users.map((user: any) => {
          return this.getUserPhotoUrl(user.username).pipe(
            tap((image: any) => {
              user.image = image;
            })
          )
        })
        return forkJoin(imagesApis);
      })
    ))
  );
}

Full Code:
@Component({
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
      <div class="avatar">
        <img [src]="user.image" />
      </div>
      <span>{{user.username}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  `
})
export class SomeComponent {
  sub!: Subscription;
  users$: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.apollo.watchQuery<users: User[]>({query: usersQuery}).valueChanges.pipe(map(result => result.data.users.map((data: any) => {
      data.image = 'https://placehold.co/600x400'// placeholder image
      return data;
    })));
    this.lazyLoadImages();
  }

  lazyLoadImages() {
    if(this.sub) {
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.sub = this.user$.pipe(
      switchMap((usersData: any) => from(usersData).pipe(
        bufferCount(6),
        concatMap((users: any) => {
          const imagesApis = users.map((user: any) => {
            return this.getUserPhotoUrl(user.username).pipe(
              tap((image: any) => {
                user.image = image;
              })
            )
          })
          return forkJoin(imagesApis);
        })
      ))
    );
  }

  getUserPhotoUrl(username: string) {
    return this.http.get(`.../user/${username}/photo`);
  }

}

